# how to get the user permission of a folder and assign it to another folder in Linux

Tags: bash, sh

How do would i parse the user and group information of a folder and assign the same to another folder.
ls -l  gives the information but. is there a command to parse this information?

Comment: Why would you parse it? Just `chown --reference=other_folder`? As for parsing see [stat(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat).

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: What is "linxu"? Just in case, Linux is not Bash and Bash is not Linux.

Answer (score 5):

2 options: using `stat`, or using `chown --reference`

The simplest solution is to use the 'chwon --reference`

```
chown --reference="$SRC" "$DEST"
```

Alternatively, possible to use the 'stat' command to extract attribute of a file, and construct the `chown` command. Not needed here, but might be useful to for other cases - e.g., when there is a need to change the UID, without changing the group, etc.

```
SRC=source-folder
DEST=dest-folder
chown $(stat -c '%u:%g' "$SRC") "$DEST"
```